# eclemma - how to ignore source

Tags: junit, code-coverage, emma

I'm using junit/eclemma; it works great, except I'd like to instruct eclemma to ignore certain methods or classes.  For example, how would i instruct eclemma to ignore getters/setters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify in the preferences which classes to ignore using a regexp ("Only path entries matching"). See http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/preferences.html for details.

I don't think you can ignore methods though.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried for about 30 minutes configuring this path...couldn't get it to work.  If you've got this working would you please give me an example.  Let's say my prj is called ABC, and the class I want to cover is src/org/abc/MyClass123.java.  

I changed the config to src/org/abc/MyClass123.java but it keeps telling me that "no classes are selected fro coverage...".  I removed MyClass123.java from the path and it still complained; i replaced with a star and it still complained.  I'm at a loss.

Oh I'm using a mac, thought i'm not sure how that would affect this setting

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the feature might be broken, for me it has absolutely no effect on anything!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with "-classpath.*" or any other combination I could come up with.

Comment: Hi dplass, could you please share an example ?