# Eclipse Kelper EclEmma code covarage exclude

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, code-coverage, eclemma

I'm trying to exclude certain packages from eclipse code coverage tool EclEmma.

I've found this post [How do I ignore scanning certain classes using EclEmma and Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448603/how-do-i-ignore-scanning-certain-classes-using-eclemma-and-eclipse) but it's not very useful.
I've tried changing the code coverage preferences with no result.
I even tried to change run coverage configuration by giving arguments like -ix -com.foo.* with no result.

Using maven so as an alternative I can use JaCoCo maven plugin but I would need an example for it.

Please don't answer with just a link like http://eclemma.org/userdoc/preferences.html .

Thanks!